# When creating a regional node pool with gcloud. The nodes do not register

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

When running the following `gcloud` command on my existing GKE cluster

```
SCOPES=(
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
)

gcloud beta container node-pools create $POOL_NAME \
--machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
--disk-size $DISK_SIZE \
--enable-autorepair \
--enable-autoscaling \
--min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 4 \
--cluster $CLUSTER \
--zone $ZONE \
--num-nodes 1 \
--scopes $(printf ",%s" "${SCOPES[@]}")
```

(Note this is regional, so using the beta command - I suspect this doesn't happen with non-regional clusters)
I get the following error:

```
    Creating node pool pool-alpha...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.node-pools.create) Operation [<Operation
 endTime: u'2018-03-29T08:56:14.989660264Z'
 name: u'operation-1522311735033-87b12027'
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(CREATE_NODE_POOL, 7)
 selfLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-d/operations/operation-1522311735033-87b12027'
 startTime: u'2018-03-29T08:22:15.03391313Z'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: u'All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered. Cluster may be unhealthy.'
 targetLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-d/clusters/digibet-prod/nodePools/pool-alpha'
 zone: u'europe-west1-d'>] finished with error: All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered. Cluster may be unhealthy.
```

And indeed, the nodes are created but aren't registered on the cluster. A bug with GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anton Kostenko gave the answer on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667351/when-creating-a-node-pool-multi-zone-with-gcloud-the-nodes-do-not-register-on

It was a problem with my `--scopes $(printf ",%s" "${SCOPES[@]}")` line which was adding an extra comma at the end which is (somewhat understandably) not validated on the gcloud cli and breaks some internal GKE node registration process

I changed it to `--scopes $(IFS=','; echo "${SCOPES[*]}")` (no trailing comma) and now it works